# Spring 3 form validation shows error messages but field name not displayed

Tags: forms, spring, validation, annotations, field-names

I have a 2 item form, that requires that both fields be entered.  I'm using annotated validations, and am getting error messages, but they do not print the field name, just "may not be blank" instead of "one may not be blank" where one is the field name.

Any ideas?  This is a pretty simple example:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
 public class HomeController
{

private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory
                                            .getLogger(HomeController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model)
{
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
    model.addAttribute("homeformitem", new HomeFormItem());
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String home(
        @ModelAttribute("homeformitem") @Valid HomeFormItem item,
        BindingResult result)
{
    logger.info("Posting form");
    logger.info(item.toString());
    if (result.hasErrors())
    {
        return "home";
    } else
    {
        logger.info("No Errors");
        return "done";
    }
}
}
```

Here is the form.  I get the error message, but not the field name.

## Form Validation!

```
    <f:form method="post" modelAttribute="homeformitem">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend> 
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="3"><f:errors path="*"/></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><f:label path="one" for="one">One: </f:label></td>
            <td><f:input path="one" /></td>
            <td><f:errors path="one" cssClass="errorblock"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><f:label path="two" for="two">Two: </f:label></td>
            <td><f:input path="two" /></td>
            <td><f:errors path="two" cssClass="errorblock"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Test" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</f:form>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36344999/1030527 for a solution which provides the validated field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `validation.properties` file at `/WEB-INF/messages` with an entry similar to this (for example):

```
NotEmpty.homeFormItem.one=The field {0} is empty
```

And don't forget to add a spring bean to resolve your validation messages:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/validation" />
</bean>
```