# Spring forms don't display error messages

Tags: java, spring

I have web application on spring.I have so form:

```
<form:form action="submitFormAdd"  id="formId" method="GET" modelAttribute="myCandidate">
 <label for="nameInput" path="name"> Name</label>
 <form:input path="name" id="nameInput"></form:input>
 <form:errors path="name" cssclass="error"></form:errors>
</form:form>
```

and so handler:

```
@RequestMapping("/submitFormAdd")
    public String submitFormAdd(Model model
            ,@ModelAttribute @Valid Candidate myCandidate
            ,BindingResult result
            ,@ModelAttribute("skillsIdList") Set<Skill> skills
            ,@ModelAttribute("vacanciesForCandidate") Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate){
         if(result.hasErrors()) {
                return "candidateDetailsAdd";
            }
         return "candidateMenu";
    }
```

if I type less 10 symbols result.hasErrors() equals true, but I don't see errors on jsp page( 
class from model:

```
public class Candidate {
   @Size(min=10)
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
}
```

how to fix it?

P.S.
properties(/ui/src/main/resources/messages.properties):

```
Size.myCandidate.name = more size please
NotNull = Field cannot be left blank
NotEmpty = not empty
```

and config:

```
public class UiConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring 3 form validation shows error messages but field name not displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105282/spring-3-form-validation-shows-error-messages-but-field-name-not-displayed)

Comment: Not 100% sure but seems that you are missing the message-file.properties for errors validation and the properly config.

Comment: at this topics says don't display field name, but my problem - don't display error messages

Comment: araknoid, I added info to topic

Comment: Try to move your messages.properties from there to /WEB-INF/messages and change the config path.

Comment: How I can change config path?

Comment: add this bean to your `contextApplication.xml`: `<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
</bean>`

Comment: my IDE don't see org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource‌​

Comment: http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/

Comment: Do you have the `spring-context.jar` and maybe `spring-context-support.jar` as dependency?

Comment: I make so above link. maybe I forget something

Comment: right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924902/2032856

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw it now, you didn't have indicated which is the model attribute for the `myCandidate` method input.

You have to change

```
@ModelAttribute @Valid Candidate myCandidate
```

into

```
@ModelAttribute("myCandidate") @Valid Candidate myCandidate
```