# Spring Boot - custom validation message with annotation parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

I want to create my custom validation messages with Spring Boot/MVC Validation.

I found following setup working:

```
public class RegisterCredentials {

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=15)
    private String username;

    ...

}
```

messages.properties:

```
NotEmpty.registerCredentials.username = Username field cannot be empty.
NotNull.registerCredentials.username = Username field cannot be empty.
Size.registerCredentials.username = Username length must be between 3 and 15 characters.
```

After that I wanted to replace fixed values min=3 and max=15 with attributes. I tried like that, **but it didn't worked** (it works in @Size(message="..") annotation):

```
Size.registerCredentials.username = Username length must be between {min} and {max} characters.
```

Then I found following code working..:

```
Size.registerCredentials.username = Username length must be between {1} and {2} characters.
```

Well.. almost, because it produces following message:

```
Username length must be between 15 and 3 characters.
```

Replacing order of these {1} and {2} solves the problem, however it produces confusing code in futher analyze.

Is there a solution to solve this problem with clean code?

Comment: the order is start from 0,not 1,why you start with 1?

Comment: {0} is "username", the name of validated field. {3} and {4} don't work

Comment: This is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36344999/1210301 with the mention of `SpringValidatorAdapter`.

If you alphabetically order, then `max` is `{1}` and `min` is `{2}`.