# Display name of properties when looping through errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring so bear with me!

I am trying to adjust the display name of properties of an entity in Spring boot.

I have a form with the following inside to display all errors:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="e : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}" th:class="${e.global}? globalerr : fielderr">
        <span th:text="${e.global}? '*' : ${e.fieldName}">The field name</span>
        <span th:text="${e.message}">The error message</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That results in the following message upon invalid input:

> Error Saving New User - Please Try Again
>   lastName must not be empty 
>   firstName size must be between 1 and 30
>   lastName size must be between 1 and 30
>   firstName must not be empty

I have tried adjusting the property to accommodate a display name to no avail:

```
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@DisplayName("Last Name")
public String lastName;
```

I get this error :

> Display name not applicable to field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Validation custom messages - field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249937/spring-validation-custom-messages-field-name)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check properties and more information about your spring application. I recommend you to use: [Spring Boot Actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/).

and [more details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator)

Comment: Actuator is not related to custom property name for validation.