# Formatting validation message in javax.validation annotations (@NotBlank)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, dto

I am trying to add message to the `javax.validation` annotations in my Spring Boot app as shown below:

```
public static final String CANNOT_EMPTY = "%s field cannot be empty";


@Value
public class CreatePostRequest {

    @NotBlank(message = String.format(CANNOT_EMPTY, title))
    private String title;

    // other fields
}
```

I am getting "Attribute value must be constant" error for the `format()` method. So, how should I properly set messages for the `javax.validation` annotations in my API requests? I do not want to add text to all of the fields and instead try to manage them in a Constant class and add the constant text variables to that annotations (for now, no need internationalization).

So, is there a better way? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to handle it in a `RestControllerAdvice`, where you can easily append a property name to a message. For example, you can define a `RestControllerAdvice` as shown below:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<List<String>> handleValidationErrors(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    List<String> errors =
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(i -> i.getField() + " " + i.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

The response for the field marked as `@NotBlank` would be `["title must not be blank"]`, and if you want to add a custom message `@NotBlank(message="field cannot be empty")` the response would be `["title field cannot be empty"]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it sounds good. Bot I am looking a more professional way that is dedicated to this purpose like `MessageSource`. As far as I see after some search, it also support intrenationalization. I use @ControllerAdvice and Global Exception handler in my project, but this time I am looking for a specific and more elegant solution for this issue.

Comment: By the way, I cannot vote up as I have not enough repo. Would you consider any vote up pls?

Comment: And do you have any idea about MessageSource? Would you suggest to use it for this scenario?

Comment: Check [bernie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36344999/10231374), it should be useful if you want localized messages and field names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but MessageSource seems to be clearer than that approach. Nevertheless, I opened a new question about that. Could you have a look at that? >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75568330/custom-validation-message-in-spring-boot-with-internationalization